# JAXB does not generate Java class for <wsdl:message>

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, webservice-client

I have followed the Spring guide [Consuming a SOAP web service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/#initial) to create a SOAP service client, but I have found that no any Java class generated for **wsdl:message** from the WSDL file. Only schema types are generated.

As a result, in order to invoking **getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive()**, we have to construct the request object manually.

Why **maven-jaxb2-plugin** does not generate class for wsdl:message? And how can we make it  generate these missing classes?

The used WSDL file as below shown

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
                  xmlns:tns="http://www.test.com/soap/jacky/client"
                  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                  xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
                  targetNamespace="http://www.test.com/soap/jacky/client">
    <wsdl:types/>

    <wsdl:message name="retrieveResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="retValue" type="xsd:string"/>
    </wsdl:message>

    <wsdl:message name="retrieveRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
        <wsdl:part name="flag" type="xsd:boolean"/>
    </wsdl:message>

    <wsdl:portType name="DemoSoap">
        <wsdl:operation name="retrieve" parameterOrder="name flag">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:retrieveRequest" name="retrieveRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:retrieveResponse" name="retrieveResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>

    <wsdl:binding name="DemoBinding" type="tns:DemoSoap">
        <wsdlsoap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="retrieve">
            <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>
            <wsdl:input name="retrieveRequest">
                <wsdlsoap:body  use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="retrieveResponse">
                <wsdlsoap:body  use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>

    <wsdl:service name="DemoClient">
        <wsdl:port binding="tns:DemoBinding" name="Demo">
            <wsdlsoap:address location="http://www.test.com/soap/jacky/client"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>

</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: Try to insert the <wsdl:types/> this [countries.xsd](https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/) file. Your WSDL no schema. The maven-jaxb2-plugin  to generate a Java class from schema. So in your WSDL, <wsdl:types><xs:schema> schema contents </xs:schema> </wsdl:types>. The maven-jaxb2-plugin generate only from schema not message. If you want to generate it have to move the retrieveResponse and retrieveRequest inside schema.

Comment: Did you manage to get this working? I have the same issue

Comment: @sem10 As Bench said, the Jaxb does not support generating stub code for <message>. You could try Apache Axis2 instead or hand writing the code.